# How to know the size of loaded drawable in Android?

Tags: android, drawable

I did

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_deletebutton, null);
System.out.println(drawable.getBounds());
```

and got

```
I/System.out: Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
```

Why? And how to know the size of "drawable", which is stored in file?

Ny drawable looks like

[image]

Comment: You want to know the height and width right? did you tried `drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` & `drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()`

Answer (score 1):

The `getBounds()` method returns the bounds of the drawable if it's already visible on the screen. So take a look at this code.

```java
// Before
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_deletebutton, null);
System.out.println(drawable.getBounds());
```

> Output : Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)

```java
//After
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_deletebutton, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
System.out.println(drawable.getBounds());
```

> Output : Rect(0, 0 - 88, 88)

In the second case, it will return the bounds as a `Rect` object where the top-left corner is the (0,0) point, and the bottom-right corner represents the drawable's dimensions.

If you need to get the drawable size without having it visible on the screen you have to follow @Mouaad solution and use `drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` and `drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()` methods to find them.